# How do I hide a part of a form and make it visible only on clicking a "Add another" button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please note that on clicking the button multiple text field boxes become visible and not only one!

Comment: I have another question, which you should include in your description: Is it possible "Add another" button to be clicked multiple times and what should happen after the first and after the second click (if possible)?

Comment: @Minister, if _you_ have a question, it would be best if you start a new question on SO rather.

Comment: @ZaLiTHkA, it's a clarification question to the question above (not another question). I imagine a form with file fields, where you have "Add another" button, so you can add more files (for example, file field + title for the file on multiple rows). This is the reason to ask the 'user3205736' to clarify the question in case the answers below don't help to find a proper solution. (I'm sorry if my English is too poor yet and it wasn't clear in my first comment)

Comment: Fair point, however it should be noted; even when duplicating, targeting and reading multiple copies of a `file` input field, there should be no difference from the UI point of view to a `text` or `input` field. Hence my suggestion for a new question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put the form inside a container
2. Set the container's CSS to `display:none`
3. Set up a click handler on some element that triggers jQuery's show/hide methods

Your HTML:

```
<a id="toggleform" href="#">Toggle Form</a>
<div id="hideform">
    // form elements in here
</div>
```

Your javascript:

```
$( "#toggleform" ).on( "click", function() {
  $('#hideform').toggle();
});
```

Or if you don't want to toggle the hiding:

```
$( "#toggleform" ).on( "click", function() {
  $('#hideform').show();
});
```

Your CSS:

```
#hideform {display:none;}
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/AkHQa/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple jQuery for your situation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    input[type='text']
    {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form id='frm1'>
    <input type='text' />
    <input type='text' />
    <input type='text' />
    <button id='btnShowInputs'>Show Inputs</button>

  </form>
  <script>
      $("#btnShowInputs").click(function () {
          $("#frm1 input[type='text']").css("display", "block");
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:show_text_boxes();" value="Show Textboxes" />
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:hide_text_boxes();" value="Hide Textboxes" />

<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="textbox1" style="display:none;"/>
<input type="text" id="textbox2" name="textbox2" style="display:none;" />
<input type="text" id="textbox3" name="textbox3" style="display:none;" />
```

**JS**

```
function show_text_boxes()
{

    document.getElementById('textbox1').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('textbox2').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('textbox3').style.display='block';

}

function hide_text_boxes()
{

    document.getElementById('textbox1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('textbox2').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('textbox3').style.display='none';

}
```

[**SEE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vz9pp/)