# How To jQuery toggle() and Hide Toggle Link or Button?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am using PHP sessions to to provide specific forms on a page and need to toggle between a "show form" link and the form. I have this working using jQuery toggle(), but I cannot figure out how to prevent the "show form" link from displaying in both toggle states.

I have experimented with jQuery hide() after toggle(), but this made everything disappear, and I have tried using CSS visibility: hidden (which also just caused everything, including the PHP content, to disappear).

```
<div id="togLink">
<?php echo $JQclick; ?>
</div>

<div id="showForm">
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/formInc.php'; ?>
</div>

<script>
function toggleForm() {
  $("#showForm").toggle();
  $("#togLink").toggle();
}

$("#togLink").click(function() {
  toggleForm();
});

$("#showForm").click(function() {
  toggleForm();
});
</script>
```

The above code works, but the PHP output is displayed in both toggle states (which, I know, is the expected behaviour). As I said above, I need some way of making the toggle state "either or" - clickable link or form, not both. Can anyone offer any suggestions for this?

...
...

CSS code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'blair_capsregular';
    src: url('../.typefaces/blair_caps-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../typefaces/blair_caps-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

#ExBox {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.titleBar {
    width:100%;
}

.Tbox {
    float:left; height:25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'blair_capsregular';
}

#box {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin: 0;
    position: static;
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#box a:link {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#box a:visited {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Tbox:nth-child(1) {
    width:33.3%;
}

.Tbox:nth-child(2) {
    width:33.3%;
}

.Tbox:nth-child(3) {
    width:33.3%;
}

.clearRed {
    clear: both;
    color: red;
}

.Tbox a:link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Tbox a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Tbox a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Tbox a:active {
    color: hotpink;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Tbox a:focus {
    color: hotpink;
    text-decoration: none;
}





/* FORM CSS - Placeholder colors */
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #9b9b9b;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #9b9b9b;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #9b9b9b;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #9b9b9b;
}
::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
   color:    #9b9b9b;
}

textarea::placeholder { color: #9b9b9b; font-family: arial; }

/* Colors for focused fields */

input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=email]:focus, textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #00C5BE;
}

/* Input styling */

textarea {
   font-family: arial;
   width: 27rem;
   font-size: 1rem;
   padding: 0.6rem;
   margin-right: 0.5rem;
   margin-left: 0.5rem;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
   color: #9b9b9b !important;
}

.contact-form-div input {
   display: block;
   font-size: 1rem;
   width: 27rem;
   padding: 0.6rem;
   margin: 0.5rem;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
   color: #9b9b9b !important;
}

.contact-form-div input[type=submit] {
   width: auto;
   background-color: #00C5BE;
   border: none;
   color: #fff !important;
   font-size: 1em;
   padding: 10px 50px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: normal;
}

/* Hide the fake field */
#m66 {
   display: none;
}


/* VERTICAL SLIDER */


* { margin:0; padding:0; }
a { text-decoration: none; }  

.expand {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;   
  line-height: 50px;

  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
 }

 .expand:target {
  height: 50px;
}

.close {
    max-height: 0;
}

/* JQUERY TESTING */

.box{
    display:none;
}

#showForm {
  display: none;
}
```

...
...

Thanks to Grant Noe this is almost working. With the above code everything works perfectly ...except that clicking on the form causes it to disappear. Grant has since revised the code (again, thanks); but the revised code, whilst addressing the problem of the disappearing form, has a visible "*contact form*" link in both toggle states and loads the form first, not the link. The latter should be simple to fix; but I cannot figure out how to show either the *contact form* link **or** the form, not both in both toggle states.

The code, when using Grant's revised code, is as follows:

```
<div id="togLink">
<?php echo $JQclick; ?>
</div>

<div id="showForm">
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/form.php'; ?>
</div>

<script>
$("#togLink").click(function() {
  $("#showForm").toggle();
  $("#contactForm").toggle();
});
</script>


@font-face {
    font-family: 'blair_capsregular';
    src: url('../.typefaces/blair_caps-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../typefaces/blair_caps-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

#ExBox {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.titleBar {
    width:100%;
}

.Tbox {
    float:left; height:25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'blair_capsregular';
}

#box {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin: 0;
    position: static;
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#box a:link {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#box a:visited {
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Tbox:nth-child(1) {
    width:33.3%;
}

.Tbox:nth-child(2) {
    width:33.3%;
}

.Tbox:nth-child(3) {
    width:33.3%;
}

.clearRed {
    clear: both;
    color: red;
}

.Tbox a:link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Tbox a:visited {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Tbox a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Tbox a:active {
    color: hotpink;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.Tbox a:focus {
    color: hotpink;
    text-decoration: none;
}





/* FORM CSS - Placeholder colors */
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #9b9b9b;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #9b9b9b;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #9b9b9b;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #9b9b9b;
}
::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
   color:    #9b9b9b;
}

textarea::placeholder { color: #9b9b9b; font-family: arial; }

/* Colors for focused fields */

input[type=text], input[type=email], textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=email]:focus, textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #00C5BE;
}

/* Input styling */

textarea {
   font-family: arial;
   width: 27rem;
   font-size: 1rem;
   padding: 0.6rem;
   margin-right: 0.5rem;
   margin-left: 0.5rem;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
   color: #9b9b9b !important;
}

.contact-form-div input {
   display: block;
   font-size: 1rem;
   width: 27rem;
   padding: 0.6rem;
   margin: 0.5rem;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
   color: #9b9b9b !important;
}

.contact-form-div input[type=submit] {
   width: auto;
   background-color: #00C5BE;
   border: none;
   color: #fff !important;
   font-size: 1em;
   padding: 10px 50px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: normal;
}

/* Hide the fake field */
#m66 {
   display: none;
}


/* VERTICAL SLIDER */


* { margin:0; padding:0; }
a { text-decoration: none; }  

.expand {
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;   
  line-height: 50px;

  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  height: 0;
 }

 .expand:target {
  height: 50px;
}

.close {
    max-height: 0;
}

/* JQUERY TESTING */

.box{
    display:none;
}

#togLink {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#togLink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#showForm,
#contactForm {
  width: 425px;
  height: 550px;
}

#showForm {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#contactForm {
  background-color: #AAA;
  display: none;
}
```

I have not added-in contactForm to the HTML side of things, because it does not fix the persistent "*contact form*" link and leaves an ugly background-colour box behind even when hiding the form but failing to hide the link.

...
...

**26 May 2019:** with reference to a reply by **rg88** [ [How do I hide a part of a form and make it visible only on clicking a "Add another" button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202359/) ] *this* is what finally worked:

```
<a id="togLink" href="#"><?php echo $formClick; ?></a>
<div id="togForm"><?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/form.php'; ?>
</div>

<script>
$( "#togLink" ).on( "click", function() {
  $('#togForm').toggle();
});

</script>
#togForm {
  display: none;
}
```

There is still the issue of not being able to make the words "*Contact Form*" disappear when the form is loaded or being able to replace the words with something else, but it appears that it is not possible to make this happen because the Contact Form link (in this case) is the toggle point and therefore has to remain constant in all toggle states.

Comment: If you don't want `#showForm` to ever show, just add a CSS rule, like `display: none`

Comment: Thanks, but I made a mistake there, and visibility: none is not working as I had hoped, - it also causes everything to disappear (and not just the link line).

Comment: If you want the `require` to be invisible, you'll have to surround it with an element of some sort.

Comment: The proper format for visibility is ``visibility: hidden``, but you don't want to use that (most likely) because it retains the placeholder for the element instead of making it entirely disappear. That will leave a big, empty vacuum on your page. Be sure you're applying your css only to the elements where you want to hide things. It would be helpful if you posted your CSS code in the question.

Comment: I have just tried using a nested div for the PHP require, but this just caused the toggled form to disappear (or be hidden); whilst the PHP link remained visible. I think the answer lies with jQuery remove (), detach (), or empty (); but I have not been able to get these working as expected either.

Answer (score 0):

You're toggling just the one element right now, given this format: `$(toggled-element).toggle();`. You'll need to toggle both elements like this:

```
$('#togLink').click(function(){
  $('#showForm').toggle();
  $('#contactForm').toggle();
});
```

If you initially want the link showing and the form hidden, you could hide the form with css with `display: none;`, or at the top of your html in a script with `$('#showForm').hide();`. So the total result would be something like this:

```js
$("#togLink").click(function() {
  $("#showForm").toggle();
  $("#contactForm").toggle();
});
```

```css
#togLink {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#togLink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#showForm,
#contactForm {
  width: 425px;
  height: 550px;
}

#showForm {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#contactForm {
  background-color: #AAA;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="togLink">Toggle Form</div>
<div id="showForm"></div>
<div id="contactForm"></div>
```

Let me know if I missed something.

### Changelog:

I added the `#contactForm` div that's not seen in OP to adjust to OP use-case requests. The clarification occurred in the comments on my answer.

Comment: Again, thanks, but this does not work for me, either: without modifying the code at all, the PHP output ( "_contact form_" ) displays, and disappears when clicked on, but the form does not display at all.

Comment: It would be easier to help with more code, but you should still be able to apply the principles here to what you're working with. Specify specific elements to toggle with ``.toggle()``, and hide initial elements in css with ``display: none``. I'll try to update my code in a few to adapt to what I think it is you're looking for.

Comment: @YTreehuggerCymru code updated to what I think you're asking, but I'm not sure. I added a new div that's meant to represent the contact form, and the now constant "toggle form" button just switches between the two. Again, you should be able to apply these principles to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The second part, with the link showing initially, works _perfectly_, - thanks. I have voted for you, but I do not have the reputation on this site for my vote to show publicly.

Comment: Wonderful, I'm glad that it worked for you! No worries on the voting-- if you accept the answer, that will work.

Comment: There is actually a problem, and one which I should have picked up on: the form cannot be filled-in because clicking on it causes it to disappear. I have tried to fix this with both return false; and event.preventDefault(), but neither seem able to prevent the default toggle from happening when clicking on the form.

Comment: With my code the form shouldn’t disappear when you click on it. Only when you click the toggle button.

Comment: You are right, - thanks, but now that I have gone over your code again and got it working I now have a "contact form" link that is present in both toggle states. The addition of a contactForm id does not fix this and only serves to hide both toggle states entirely.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re needing/asking. It might be a good idea to open a new question (and show more of your code) if what you’re wanting now is part of a separate issue.

Comment: I think I have all the pieces now, so the problem is simply getting them to work in the required way. - I will expand on my original question to clarify what the situation is.

Comment: I don't see the "contact form link" that say won't disappear anywhere in your code.

Comment: The contact form link has to stay, ie: there is absolutely no way that it can be removed; so it either has to be formatted or, maybe, replaced with an image or the like, but it would appear that it is not possible to, for example, click on it and to have it not display with the toggled content.

Answer (score -1):

Placing the PHP in an HTML element allows you to have separate control over that element:

```
<div id="togLink">foo
<?php echo $JQclick; ?>
</div>

<div id="showForm">bar
<span>glorp<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/formInc.php'; ?></span>
</div>
```

Use CSS to hide the element:

```
span {
  display: none;
}
```

Then avoid the element to be toggled, using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('#togLink').click(function(){
  console.log('click');
  $('#showForm').not('span').toggle();
});
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/m7dhub1o/)

Comment: Thanks, but neither the demo or the code in use on the webpage work for me: the demo works in the way that I would expect toggle () to work, so foo always remains. I am uncertain as to the use of glorp, too.

Comment: Glorp should never be displayed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard interesting answer! I had never heard of glorp before, so that ended up being educational-- thank you.

Comment: No, I realise that glorp should never be displayed, now, but it puzzled me at the time because I normally use &nbsp; in such cases. I still cannot get this to work, though.